# When solving a S-L eigenvalue problem like $y'' + (\lambda + 1)y = 0$, is it better to set $\lambda =/>/< 0$, or $\lambda + 1 =/>/< 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

So if I'm given a Strum Liouville equation in a form similar to the one I've mentioned above, which method gives me the correct eigenvalues and eigenfunctions?

Should I be using $$\lambda= 0, \lambda> 0, \lambda< 0$$
or,
$$\lambda + 1 = 0, \lambda + 1 > 0, \lambda + 1 < 0$$ and then setting $\lambda + 1 = k^2$ or something?

I've seen both be mentioned in multiple places on MathSE, but not in any textbooks or the like, so at this point, I'm genuinely just really confused.

Does it matter which one I use? Or does it depend on something?

I'd really appreciate if anyone could answer! Thanks!

Comment: They are just shifted relative to each other. If it helps, set $\lambda + 1 = \tilde{\lambda}$ and check the cases $\tilde{\lambda} > 0, \tilde{\lambda} = 0, \tilde{\lambda} < 0$, solve and then revert back to $\lambda$.

Comment: Ohh I see. So it doesn't matter which one I use? The second option sort of gets rid of the entire $y$ term, while the first one leaves it there, so I felt like they might both give different answers...?

Comment: They are different, they are shifted relative to eachother. You know how to solve the problem $y'' + \lambda y = 0$ no doubt, so for $y'' + (\lambda + 1)y = 0$ just let $\tilde{\lambda} = \lambda + 1$ and follow your usual procedure, then revert back to $\lambda$ afterwards.

Comment: Ohhh alright, alright, that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ODE $y''+(\lambda+1)y=0,\ y(0) = 0,\ y(L) = 0$ admits as trivial solution $y=0$. As we known the general solution, assuming $\lambda+1>0$ is given by $y=c_1\cos(\sqrt{\lambda+1}t)+c_2\sin(\sqrt{\lambda+1}t)$ so we have at the boundary

$$
\cases{
y(0) = c_1 = 0\\
y(L) = c_1\cos(\sqrt{\lambda+1}L)+c_2\sin(\sqrt{\lambda+1}L)=0
}
$$

Non trivial solutions are obtained when $\sin(\sqrt{\lambda+1}L)=0$ or when

$$
\sqrt{\lambda+1}L=2k\pi\Rightarrow \lambda = \left(\frac{2k\pi}{L}\right)^2-1
$$

Analogous procedure can be applied when $\lambda+1<0$

Comment: Yes yess. Just wanted to confirm if there was any preference/reasoning for choosing one of the two possibilities e.g. $\lambda >0$ vs $\lambda + 1 > 0$

Comment: The reason is that the sign of $\lambda+1$ defines the type of solution. If $\lambda+1 < 0$ then the solution template is $y = c_1 e^{\sqrt{\lambda+1}t}+c_2 e^{-\sqrt{\lambda+1}t}$

Comment: Of course in the first case we have $\lambda > -1$

Comment: Ahh yes alright. So this is a seemingly easier to solve case. What about with $y''-2y'+(\lambda +1)y = 0$? I'd still solve it the same way? (Essentially, this is the problem that I'm trying to work on, I asked the one in the question just for some simple clarification, but I just want to confirm if it's the same case with the equation that I'm actually trying to solve.)

Comment: In this case, assuming $\lambda > 0$ the general solution is $y = e^{t}(c_1\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}t)+c_2\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}t))$ and thus the considerations regarding the boundary conditions are the same and the conclusions are equivalent.